# Create user with ldap entry

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I have installed [LDAP](https://www.drupal.org/project/LDAP) module and configured.

After that walk through *admin-> configuration->people->ldap*, here I added the server, in authentication I enabled the added server.

Finally in user page I selected **Show option on user create form to determine how account conflict is resolved** and in basic provisioning ldap block selected the **added server name**.

Now I want walk through *people->add user*, I want to create a user with ldap authentication so when I select **Create corresponding LDAP entry**. I am unable to check the box.

Why this? please help me on this I am breaking my head to trigger it out. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: check these http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21883/create-a-new-user-in-ldap-not-wherever-drupal-normally-creates-it,  https://www.drupal.org/node/1685352

Comment: @Adi: Thanks for responding to me...i will try and get back to u.